# Derailleur hanger reverse

Tags: derailleur-rear, derailleur-hanger

It looks that the **derailleur hanger is reverse** and I've tried to check for a new one to replace and it seems to be very rare.

Is there any workaround to change it with a regular hanger?

[image]

Comment: You like to replace the hanger fort it is not good any more? And not because it is reverse. Having the bolt before the axle only makes it difficult to find replacement? Is it a folding bike?

Comment: @gschenk, yes it's folding dahon eco 6. 
Yes, it makes is it difficult to find a replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derailleur hanger appears to be installed correctly.

Notice there is a small bolt forward of the axle, that obviously goes in a hole in the  dropout and stops the hanger falling off when the wheel is out. The hanger also aligns with the dropout slot to allow the wheel to be removed.

I think your confusion comes from the fact that hangers on more modern bikes tend to have the lug where the derailleur mounting hole is located *behind* the axle, but these bikes also have downward facing dropout slots rather than rearward facing ones.

---

Edit after comments clarifying question:

The only new derailleurs that are designed for a 5 speed bike are Tourney. You could actually use any 8 or 9 speed derailleur as the actuation ratios are the same, but I doubt that would work any better than a Tourney derailleur on the 5 speed freewheel.

If you want to fit a different derailleur what you want is a 'conversion' derailleur hanger for horizontal dropouts that is held in place by the axle nuts and provides a standard M10 threaded mounting hole.

Googling for 'derailleur hanger horizontal dropouts' should get you started. What you are looking for is something like [this](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-128.html) - note I'm not sure if that's *exactly* what you need and I'm not making a recommendation.

Comment: The derraliuer is installed correctly.
But I need to change him since the screw on (L) is broken.
My questions if I have to change it by exactly the same type with reversed hanger. or there is any workaround?

Comment: It is a derailleur where the hanger is an integral part of the design. It used to be that way before the hanger became part of the bike.

Comment: @MichaelD I missed the fact that the hanger is integral with the derailleur. Shimano Tourney derailleurs come with various different attachment styles. You probably want an [RD-FT55 type](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tourney/RD-FT55-SS.html)

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, I also find this:
[Shimano TZ 50](https://www.bankruptbikeparts.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=20350)
But, what I understand from the answers that there is no **workaround** to fit another derraliuer. Smth of better quality like deore or smth. like that.

Comment: @MichaelD Shopping around you might find the hanger part only. It used to be a standard part. Some (non net-based) bike stores will probably having these in their stock.